# Each checkbox shows up twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, semantic-ui

Set up:

- jQuery 3.2.1
- Semantic UI 2.1
- Chrome

HTML (based on https://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#/definition):

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="checkbox1">
        <label>Branch</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="checkbox2">
        <label>Branch</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="checkbox3">
        <label>Branch</label>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

*They are all initially checked.** The user unchecks the ones they want to deactivate.

In my JS file, I'm using the following function to get which checkboxes are checked:

```
$('input:checkbox[name=checkboxes]:checked').each(function () {
        // Do something with them
    });
```

However, each checkbox shows up twice (once in the new state - checked or unchecked, and once in the original state - all checked). This confuses my logic after this, making the checkmark pointless.

I went into Chrome Developer Tools, and used the same selector in the console. Got this back:

`input#checkbox2, input#checkbox3, input#checkbox1, input#checkbox2, input#checkbox3`

(I had unchecked `checkbox1`)

Any ideas on why it would show up twice, or what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try changing the `name` attribute to `checkboxes[]`.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checkbox[name=checkboxes[]]:checked` - unless I misunderstood?

Comment: No, change the actual elements' name attribute to `checkboxes[]`, not the jQuery selector.

Comment: So you have `<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkbox1">`.

Comment: The name is accepted; however, the selector doesn't find any of them, then. Using `$('input:checkbox[name=tooltip_fields]:checked')` gives a blank list, and `$('input:checkbox[name=tooltip_fields[]]:checked')` gives the syntax error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of head-banging, figured out the issue.
My answer is here, for posterity:

**This is a by-product of using Semantic / the way Semantic works**

## Cause

> These checkboxes were in a modal. When Semantic initialises a modal,
>   it creates a copy of all items, and adds them to the end of the DOM.

^ This causes two copies to show up, like in my problem.

When searching by ID, the last copy of a DOM element with that ID will be used; any changes I make (checking/un-checking) will happen on the *copy*, not the original.

**Note**: this is also true for Semantic dropdowns inside modals.

## Solution

Put your checkboxes (or dropdowns) into a `div`, and give it an ID, like my original code above.

```
<div id="my_checkboxes">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="checkbox1">
        <label>Branch</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, instead of referring to them using `input` and `name`, refer to them using this parent `div`:

```
$('#my_checkboxes').children().each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below method to get the checked checkboxes

```
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function () {
   console.log($(this))
 });
```

Comment: This still prints 5 elements, just like before (2 which are actually checked, followed by all 3)

Comment: Check the fiddle, it console logs only 2 elements
https://jsfiddle.net/v73dbjms/1/

Comment: Did it fixed your issue?

Comment: No, because while your Fiddle prints 2, mine real code is still printing 5. I need try some more